# Move datagridview scroll bar by pressing button c#

Tags: c#, winforms, button, scroll, datagridview

In my WinForm project in c#,I have DataGridview that has 120 columns so this needs scrolling. But i want user press button and displays last column or specific column directly for convenience.

I do not want to add scroll control if possible, i want to handle it on "Datagridview scroll bar".

Is there any solution for that?

I added image for detail explaination.

Thanx in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `DataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex` & `DataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` to desired row and column indexes to display cell you want.

Comment: thanx:-). Sily me:-). I m not aware of this property.